# Почему не показывается Toast?

Tags: java, android, android-toast, android-broadcastreceiver

`BroadcastReceiver` запускается при неработающей программе. Для отладки хотелось увидеть `Toast`, который был задан в методе `onReceive()`. Но сообщения не было, также как и указания на ошибки. Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ресивер должен быть объявлен в манифесте.
2. Ресивер должен быть описан в отдельном java-файле.
3. Ресивер надо зарегистрировать в системе. Для этого приложение должно хотя бы раз запуститься после установки и/или принудительной остановки.
4. Ресивер должен получать какие-то сообщения. Может ему просто получать нечего.

Без кода ничего конкретнее вам тут не скажут - все экстрасенсы в отпуске.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. Вопрос задавался по памяти, и память меня подвела. Обещаю в следующий раз перепроверять. 
В общем из onReceive() Toast и правда виден. Он не виден из onHandleIntent() IntentService, который запускается в onReceive().

Вот код:
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FROM onHandleIntent()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Log.d("-----------------", "FROM onHandleIntent()");

Сообщение в логе есть, а тоста нет.
Так почему же Toast не виден. Дело, наверное, в контексте?

Comment: @iramm, Возможно да - дело в контексте. Попробуйте контекст сервиса использовать, т.е. просто `this`

Comment: Все равно не виден. Может, мне лучше удалить вопрос как неверно сформулированный. Как Вы считаете?

Comment: Помогло:
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FROM Handler in onHandleIntent()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

Comment: @iramm, удалять не надо. Вопрос про ресивер, а про него всё верно написано. Можете просто добавить ваше решение тут в дополнении вопроса или ответом. Указав, что вывод нужен был из сервиса.